# Where does human consciousness derive from according to kabbalistic teachings?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, psych-mentalhealth

In the kabbalah there is an extensive writing on how a human's soul derive from different worlds, Nefesh - Assiyah, Ruach - Yetzira etc.

Then we also have the distinction between the G-dly soul and Animal soul in chassidut.

However, what about a human's individually perceived consciousness? Where does this derive from?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30623/is-the-i-consciousness-from-the-body-or-from-the-soul

Comment: Just a technical note: distinction between G-dly sould and Animal soul is definitely mentioned by R' Chaim Vital in *Shaarey Kedushah*, and the Alter Rebbe in the *Tanya* actually cites it from there. So this distinction does not come from *chassidus*, but rather from much earlier sources.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are calling "individual perceived consciousness" correctly, the answer to your question is found in chapter 39 of the Tanya. The link follows:

http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/tanya/1/39

Individual perceived consciousness or intellect originates from Olam HaBriah and is a lavush or garment to the soul. The Alter Rebbe provides in that chapter the specific citations in kabbalistic literature addressing the idea.